# css - свойство height

Tags: html, css

Проблема такая: есть блок

```
    <div class="main" style="height: auto">
      <div style="height: 100px"></div>
    </div>
```

Родительский div (с классом 'main') будет иметь высоту 100px (как у дочернего)

Как сделать так, чтобы 'main' имел половину своей высоты (50px)?

На псевдокоде это будет выглядеть как то так

```
   height: auto/2;
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что такое можно только расчётами на js

Comment: как вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/a5meetta/

Answer (score 0):

Думаю в данном случае лучше всего использовать height : 50 %;

Comment: 50% - это половина высоты родителя, а не половина своей высоты

Answer (score 0):

я через JS решал такие вопросы, возможно не правельно на работает

```js
      $(".main").css("height", function(){
        var height = $(".main_bl").height() *2;
        return height;})
```

```css
.main_bl{
border:1px solid blue;

}
.main{
height:auto;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
      <div style="" class="main_bl">
      ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если высота неизвестна?

Comment: при любой высоте, блок с классом main будет в два высшим чем main_bl. удалили сейчас высоту и просто додал текст